# Error: Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$ImeHandler

Tags: android, appium

I'm trying to set up Appium with Android Studio and encounter loads of errors. I'm using the open source app Omni-Notes and if I include the necessary dependencies via the maven repository, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':omniNotes:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForFossDebug'.
```

> Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$ImeHandler

Sometimes it's the ImeHandler, but other times WebDriver$Options.

These are the versions I'm using:

```
compile group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '6.0.0-BETA1'
compile group:  'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.8.1'
```

I've tried things like cleaning the project, deleting .gradle, adding multidexenabled etc.

Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: Did you get a fix??

Comment: @paradox did you find a fix?

Comment: Sorry, Couldn't find a fix yet.

Comment: Sorry,  just saw your comments. With this particular project I fixed it by replacing all compiles with testCompile and by moving all my Appium tests to the test directory in the project structure view, if I remember it correctly. Did not get any errors after that.

Answer (score 0):

When I add the "Appium Jar files for Java" plugin (java-client-7.0.0.jar) I checked that it already contains the classes contained in the "Latest Appium Client Library" (selenium-java-3.141.59) as described in some tutorials on the internet.

To solve the problem do:

1. Delete the java-client-7.0.0.jar file from your project
2. Open java-client-7.0.0.jar with 7zip and delete the "org /" folder and all subfolders.
3. Include the updated java-client-7.0.0.jar in your project. Rebuild project