# AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$ImeHandler","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

Tags: android, gradle, java-8, appium

I am trying to setup Appium for my gradle based Android project but getting an error as above, can't find any workaround.These are the dependencies I have added to app/build.gradle,

```
compile (group: 'io.appium', name: 'java-client', version: '6.0.0')
        {exclude group: 'org.ow2.asm'}
compile group: 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator', name: 'uiautomator-v18', version: '2.1.3'
```

Running assembleDebug results in this error,

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$ImeHandler","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

Some SO post suggest there is a conflict in gradle dependencies, I tried excluding a few based on result of

```
/gradlew -q dependencies mobile:dependencies --configuration compile
```

but no avail . Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47992930/2231099