# Appium Test Android

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

Automating Test using Appium

I am Following This Two Tutorials

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n8QqYAXKWEU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlBrQ_-phsQ

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:358)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:219)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    .....
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/android/Desktop/Android Studio Projects/MyApplication/app/libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1021.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/android/Desktop/Android Studio Projects/MyApplication/app/libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:442)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/android/Desktop/Android Studio Projects/MyApplication/app/libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:420)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/android/Desktop/Android Studio Projects/MyApplication/app/libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:909)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$6(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:834)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:904)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:70)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Default method desugaring of `io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver` failed because it's hierarchy is incomplete. The class `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver` is missing and it is the declared super class of `io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver(classpath class)`
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
    ... 10 more
```

**Java Compiler :**

```
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/android/Desktop/Android Studio Projects/MyApplication/app/libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar

Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.


Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete


Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Default method desugaring of `io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver` failed because it's hierarchy is incomplete. The class `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver` is missing and it is the declared super class of `io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver(classpath class)`
```

**Android Errors:**

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default method desugaring of `io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver` failed because it\u0027s hierarchy is incomplete. The class `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver` is missing and it is the declared super class of `io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver(classpath class)`","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/android/Desktop/Android Studio Projects/MyApplication/app/libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ......
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
    ... 10 more
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/android/Desktop/Android Studio Projects/MyApplication/app/libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar
```

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.armcha:SpaceNavigationView:1.6.0'

    implementation files('libs/byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/guava-25.0-jre.jar')
    implementation files('libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.11.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/okio-1.14.0.jar')

   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

its not multidex problem

```
class App : MultiDexApplication
{
    constructor() : super()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        MultiDex.install(this)
    }
}
```

I am new with this type of application any one help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I think it's a multi dexing issue. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library answer to enable multidexing for your project and see whether the build passes or not.

Comment: sir multidexEnabled

Comment: It's not there in your dependencies. Did you miss out that in the question ? And also did you enable it by calling `MultiDex.install(this);` inside your `Application` class ?

Comment: @Abhishek its not multidex proble edited my question please check

Comment: In that case, if we go by the compiler errors, it says that `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver` class is missing and your `io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver` is dependent on this class. Please check if you've any Class reference error. If you don't have any reference error, then check whether **Proguard** is **enabled or not and is it removing any files from your library** ?

Comment: @Abhishek now new error `AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$Window","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}`

Comment: Use `testImplementation files('libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar')` instead of `implementation files('libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187707/discussion-between-abhishek-and-ashvin-solanki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Time I miss to add two library's in dependency

```
dependencies 
{
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.armcha:SpaceNavigationView:1.6.0'

implementation files('libs/byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar')
implementation files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
implementation files('libs/guava-25.0-jre.jar')
implementation files('libs/java-client-7.0.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.11.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/okio-1.14.0.jar')

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

//missed
implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.141.59.jar')
implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.141.59-sources.jar')

}
```

Then After Sync the Project and getting erro like

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$Window","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

Followed Answer  : [Error: Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver$ImeHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47992930/error-program-type-already-present-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverimehandler/54297103#54297103)

When I add the "Appium Jar files for Java" plugin (java-client-7.0.0.jar) I checked that it already contains the classes contained in the "Latest Appium Client Library" (selenium-java-3.141.59) as described in some tutorials on the internet.

To solve the problem do:

1. Delete the java-client-7.0.0.jar file from your project
2. Open java-client-7.0.0.jar with 7zip and delete the "org /" folder and all subfolders.
3. Include the updated java-client-7.0.0.jar in your project. Rebuild project

Comment: 2 things to suggest for your answer.
**1.** Replace the jar files with `gradle` dependencies available. While looking into your issue, I did replace them with `gradle` dependencies. It will reduce the local dependency and you don't have to put external code into your project.
**2.** Instead of manually deleting files from the `jar` and then repacking it, try to use `exclude` option given by `gradle`. That'll help both the users who are either using local dependency or `gradle` dependency available on **maven** central repo.