# Error while builiding the gradle files in android studio using Appium libraries

Tags: java, android, appium

This is my **Build.gradle** file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mynewapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'

        exclude 'org/openqa/selenium/remote/isDisplayed.js'
        exclude 'org/openqa/selenium/firefox/webdriver_prefs.json'
        exclude 'org/openqa/selenium/remote/getAttribute.js'
        exclude 'org/openqa/selenium/firefox/webdriver.xpi'
        exclude 'okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/publicsuffixes.gz'
        exclude 'org.openqa.selenium.Architecture$1'

    }
}

    dependencies {
    //    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        /*implementation 'io.particle:devicesetup:0.4.9'*/

        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
        implementation('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.41.0')
        testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:2.0.0'
        testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:6.9.10'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
        implementation files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
        implementation files('libs/byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar')
        implementation files('libs/client-combined-3.141.59.jar')
        implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
        implementation files('libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar')
        implementation files('libs/commons-exec-1.3.jar')
        implementation files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
        implementation files('libs/commons-lang3-3.7.jar')
        implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar')
        implementation files('libs/commons-validator-1.4.1.jar')
        implementation files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
        implementation files('libs/guava-21.0.jar')
        implementation files('libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar')
        implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.4.1.jar')
        implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')
        implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.4.1.jar')
        implementation files('libs/java-client-3.2.0.jar')
        implementation files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
        implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.11.0.jar')
        implementation files('libs/okio-1.14.0.jar')
        implementation files('libs/selenium-java-2.47.1.jar')
        implementation files('libs/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar')

    }
```

Then when I am running the file I am getting the error of

> **Error: Program type already present: org.openqa.selenium.Architecture$1**

I am getting this error constantly 
and due to that I am not able to run my File

this error appeared after i added the java client libraries and all other i can't say particularly which library but i think  that this is due to library can anyone suggest me the solution to this

Comment: this may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460141/appium-test-android/54490496#54490496

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki , i am getting this error after following below commands ** Error: Program type already present: com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible**

Comment: try to use exclude option with `implementation files('libs/guava-21.0.jar'){ exclude group : 'com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible'}`

Comment: I am getting this error after this Error: Program type already present: com.google.common.annotations.Beta

Comment: Thanks it helped

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have two libraries with similar component . So its causing error . You have included this dependency

```
    implementation('org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:2.41.0')
```

and Also this

```
  implementation files('libs/selenium-java-2.47.1.jar')
```

so choose wisely , which one do you need

Comment: After removing one of those dependencies i am getting this,                                                   Error: Program type already present: com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible